# Request gets overridden with other data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to get data for autocomplete using laravel. 
Controller:

```
public function collection_search(Request $request) {
      $term = $request->search;
      $serveurapObj = new Serveurap();
      $result = $serveurapObj->collectionAutocomplete();
      return response()->json($result);
}
```

Model:

```
public function collectionAutocomplete($term) {
      $where= ['m.supprime'=>'0', 's.supprime'=>'0'];
      return DB::table('serveuraps AS s')
              ->select(DB::raw('s.nom as hostname'))
              ->join('machines AS m','m.id','=','s.machine_id')
              ->join('typeserveurs AS t','t.id','=','m.typeserveur_id')
              ->where($where)
              ->where('hostname','like','%'.$term.'%')
              ->get();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">{!! __('script.serveur') !!}</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="serveur" id="relance-serveur" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Jquery/Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // relance serveur autocomplete textbox
    $('#relance-serveur').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            alert(request.term)
            $.ajax({
                url: '/scripts/relanceCollection/collection',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    search: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

I'm getting error when accessing the `search` from js in controller. 
 
Error:
[image]

I printed `$request` but it showed the json data from model. how would I get the `search` from js to controller so that I can search data based on that term ?

Comment: It would help to pass `$term` through to the model.

Comment: You didn't pass $term you get to function collectionAutocomplete. Do: $result = $serveurapObj->collectionAutocomplete($term);

Answer (score 2):

The key you are sending is `search`, not `term`. Either change your controller code to reflect that, or change the ajax data.

```js
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
        → search: request.term
    },
    ...
});
```

```php
public function collection_search(Request $request)
{
    $term = $request->search; ←
    ...
}
```

---

```js
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
        → term: request.term
    },
    ...
});
```

```php
public function collection_search(Request $request)
{
    $term = $request->term; ←
    ...
}
```

Comment: Getting the same error. I've edited the question with the error for search. Pardon me for using different image

Comment: Does the data appear in the error if you do `throw new \Exception(json_encode($request->all()));` in the first line of the method?

Comment: I can see the data in the response in the network tab in developer tools. I'm getting blank list of dropdown now, no text. But if I count the no of lines, the count is correct. but no text https://ibb.co/TLKpRYQ

Answer (score 1):

You aliased the wrong class. You don't want an instance of a Facade, ever. If you want an instance of something you want the underlying instance, not the facade.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Now, `$request` would be an instance of that class and not the Facade, `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request`.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But now I'm getting blank results, I mean just getting the list but not the text. The lines in the image are the result based on input, but I cant see the text.  https://ibb.co/TLKpRYQ

Comment: I got the result. I had to add $.map function to display label and value for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result by adding `$.map` function in success function in JS. if anyone needs it, please refer below js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var headers = {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN':'<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">'
        };
    // relance serveur autocomplete textbox
    $('#relance-serveur').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/scripts/relanceCollection/collection',
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                headers: headers,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.hostname,
                            value: item.hostname
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#relance-serveur').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
            return false;
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```